# UI Update Delegate Method Not Called

Tags: ios, swift

Working on a practice project (solution found here: https://github.com/appbrewery/ByteCoin-iOS13-Completed) where you swipe with a picker view to see the value of 1 Bitcoin in the selected currency.

Right now, I'm successfully retrieving and parsing the data from coinapi.io, but my delegate method to update the text labels isn't activating and I can't figure out why, even comparing it to the solution code.  I'm not getting any errors and it runs fine, but this update method just isn't calling.  Why not?

**ViewController.swift**

```
// CoinManager Delegate Extension Functionality
extension ViewController: CoinManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateCoin(currency: String, value: String) {
        // Test to see if it's being called
        print("didUpdateCoin Called")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Change the information presented to the user
            self.currencyLabel.text = currency
            self.bitcoinLabel.text = String(value)
        }
    }

    // If it fails, print the error that occurred
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

This is where I'm calling it.

**CoinManager.swift**

```
var delegate: CoinManagerDelegate?

func performRequest(with urlString: String, currency: String) {
        // If the url is valid
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            // Create the URLSession to request the data
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            // Create the task and session with the url
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                // If there's an error
                if error != nil {
                    // Call the error-handling function
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                    // Return without any request being performed
                    return
                }
                // If the data is retrieved successfully
                if let safeData = data {
                    // Parse the data
                    if let value = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                        print("Got to just before didUpdateCoin")
                        // The value is being passed correctly
                        print(value)
                        // Not calling, just skipping passed didUpdateCoin
                        self.delegate?.didUpdateCoin(currency: currency, value: value)
                        print("Passed didUpdateCoin")
                    }
                }
            }
            // Continue running
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

**Output**

Got to just before didUpdateCoin

9768.79

Passed didUpdateCoin

Comment: Did you assign `delegate` properly? It is most likely nil or pointing to another object. Could you add the relevant code.

Comment: Within ```override func viewDidLoad()``` make sure that you have the delegate assigned to self right below ```super.viewDidLoad()```.

Comment: That was it, Todd, thanks!  Just had to add "coinManager.delegate = self" and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is - you have not connected your delegate with second view where you want to update content

For make it works follow next steps:

1) Create Protocol

2) Create delegate variable with your protocol type, you can make it optional

3) Chose where you want to call method from your delegate

4) In related VC assign it itself

5) Subscribe to protocol

6) Add protocol stubs

7) Configure your functionality

For better understanding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBWu6TnhLeY